# I have trouble making social media buttons with material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

[image]

the following code doesn't work for making social media icons/buttons, they don't appear for no reason.

the first lines I imported material ui icons/buttons from react material ui library:(Iconbutton/AlarmIcon)

```
    import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/Button';
import AlarmIcon from '@mui/material/Icon';

const App = () => {
  const url = "https://api.quotable.io/random";
  let quoteData = {
    content: "Let time be your only competitor.",
    author: "Ahmed Saber"
  }
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState(quoteData)

  const generateQuote = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        setQuote(data)
      });
  }

  const copy = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(quote.author + " once said: " + quote.content)
    alert('copied')
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Quote Generator React App</h1>
      
      <div className="container">
        <p>{quote.content}</p>
        <span>{quote.author}</span>
        <div className="btns">
          <button onClick={copy} className="btn">Copy</button>
          <button onClick={generateQuote}>Generate Another Quote</button>
       
          
        </div>
        <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="add an alarm">
  <AlarmIcon />
</IconButton>
      </div>
    </>

  )
  
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. In particular, your code doesn't show what library is supposed to provide `IconButton` or `AlarmIcon` so its hard to tell if you are using them correctly or if you are missing dependencies.

Comment: wait a minute I will fi that

Comment: You also need to include debugging information. A good starting point would be to use the Element Inspector feature of your browser's Developer Tools to see what HTML is generated from the components I mentioned above, what CSS is applied to them, and what URLs should be requested based on those elements and styles. Then use the Network tab to find the requests for those URLs and see what the response was (e.g. a 404 Not Found error would be a bit clue as to where the problem was).

Comment: You made a typo in your imports. Check [the documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/) (in particular the examples) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the library for IconButton would be

`import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';` instead of `import IconButton from '@mui/material/Button';`

or changing the import of the actual icon from

`import AlarmIcon from '@mui/material/Icon';` to `import AlarmIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccessAlarm';` or `import AlarmIcon from '@mui/icons/AccessAlarm';` since it seems calling AlarmIcon on its own is not a recognized default material icon.

Comment: I ffixed it and the button still doesn't appear

Comment: You may need to import the actual Icon differently since it seems there's no material icon called AlarmIcon by default, instead of 

import AlarmIcon from '@mui/material/Icon';

try

import AlarmIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccessAlarm';

Comment: sorry but it's not a correct answer

Comment: it's still giving errors(not the right import)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Icons with material UI Icons using the following code.

```
import React from 'react';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import FacebookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Facebook';
import TwitterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Twitter';
import InstagramIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Instagram';

const SocialMediaButtons = () => {
return (
<div>
  <IconButton
    color="primary"
    aria-label="Facebook"
    onClick={() => window.open('https://www.facebook.com/yourpage')}
  >
    <FacebookIcon />
  </IconButton>

  <IconButton
    color="primary"
    aria-label="Twitter"
    onClick={() => window.open('https://twitter.com/yourhandle')}
  >
    <TwitterIcon />
  </IconButton>

  <IconButton
    color="primary"
    aria-label="Instagram"
    onClick={() => window.open('https://www.instagram.com/yourusername')}
  >
    <InstagramIcon />
  </IconButton>
</div>
);
};

export default SocialMediaButtons;
```